# Substitution in Vim using the capture sequence

Tags: vim, vi

I have the following lines in my text file:

```
.abc(),
.def(),
.ghi(),
.jkl(),
```

and I'd like to transform them into this:

```
.abc(abc),
.def(def),
.ghi(ghi),
.jkl(jkl),
```

I've tried `:%s/\.\(\w\+\)(\),/.\1(\1),/g` but it won't take.

Comment: Put more effort in your questions. Your poor formatting lead the first responder on a false trail.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this backslash:

```
:%s/\.\(\w\+\)(\),/.\1(\1),/g
               ^
```

which is ambiguous as the capture group has already been closed. Because of that, your patten doesn't match and your substitution does nothing.

Removing it makes your substitution work:

```
:%s/\.\(\w\+\)(),/.\1(\1),/g
```

Now, the complexity of that substitution may be required by the actual content of the actual file but it doesn't fit your sample.

- The parts that don't change before and after the parts that change can be removed:

  ```
  :%s/\(\w\+\)(/\1(\1,/g
  ```
- Since there is only one match on each line, the `/g` is useless:

  ```
  :%s/\(\w\+\)(/\1(\1
  ```